# How to call a stored procedure from a user defined function In SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server

How to call a stored procedure from a user defined function in SQL Server 2000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either you need to modify your stored procedure to be a user defined function or the other way around.

One crude way to achieve what you are looking for is to have your `exec` statement in a batch script and call that batch script from your function. Something like this:

```
create function <functionName>
exec master.sys.xp_cmpshell 'C:\storedProc.bat'
....
....

return @return
end
```

More on [`xp_cmpshell` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260689(SQL.80).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can't call regular stored procs from functions - only other functions or some extended stored procedures.  See here for the [BOL article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320(SQL.90).aspx) (from SQL 2005).  Attempting to call a standard stored proc from a UDF will result in the following error...

Msg 557, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar issue. In fact the error message is not properly formatted since `sp_executesql` is an extended stored procedure as you can check by the following script:
`select objectproperty(object_id('sp_executesql'),'IsExtendedProc')`

returns `1`

Since we can’t use `sp_executesql` even it’s an XP, I had to find another workaround by using `sp_OAMethod`. My scenario was how to find the number of rows dynamically in a table according to some criteria (`null` values in my scenario). Using `sp_OAMethod` I built the following function:

```
IF object_id(N'dbo.fc_ContaRegistros_x_Criterio') is not null DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[fc_ContaRegistros_x_Criterio]
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fc_ContaRegistros_x_Criterio (
    @str_TBName VARCHAR(100), 
    @str_Criter VARCHAR(500)
)
RETURNS BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
-- Objetivo   : Contar numero de registros de uma determinada tabela de acordo com o critério passado 
-- Criação    : Josué Monteiro Viana - 09/07/09
/*
Exemplo: 
    DECLARE @count INT
    SET @count = dbo.fc_ContaRegistros_x_Criterio('master.dbo.sysobjects', '') 
    PRINT @count
    SET @count = dbo.fc_ContaRegistros_x_Criterio('crk.dbo.acao', 'where cod_acao is null') 
    PRINT @count
*/
    DECLARE 
        @int_objSQL INT,
        @int_erros INT,
        @int_objSelectCountResult INT,
        @bint_SelectCount BIGINT,
        @sql NVARCHAR(2000)

    EXEC @int_erros = sp_OACreate 'SQLDMO.SQLServer', @int_objSQL OUTPUT
    EXEC @int_erros = sp_OASetProperty @int_objSQL, 'LoginSecure', TRUE
    EXEC @int_erros = sp_OAMethod @int_objSQL, 'Connect', null, '.'
    --SET @sql = 'SELECT count(*) FROM ' + @str_TBName + ' WHERE ' + @str_Criter 
    SET @sql = 'SELECT count(*) FROM ' + @str_TBName + ' ' + @str_Criter 
    SET @sql = 'ExecuteWithResults("' + @sql + '")'
    EXEC @int_erros = sp_OAMethod @int_objSQL, @sql, @int_objSelectCountResult OUTPUT
    EXEC @int_erros = sp_OAMethod @int_objSelectCountResult, 'GetRangeString(1, 1)', @bint_SelectCount OUT
    EXEC @int_erros = sp_OADestroy @int_objSQL
    -- debug info: not valid inside a fc
    --if @int_erros <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @int_objSQL else print 'ok'
    if @int_erros <> 0 SET @bint_SelectCount = @int_erros
    RETURN @bint_SelectCount
END
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO
```

I know your case is a little different, but I’m sure you can use this udf as a guideline to help you.

Best wishes,
Josue Monteiro Viana