# Calling procedure inside a function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to combine procedures and functions to learn more about them.

I have a table called `customer` with few columns (the column I'll be using is `sal`).

I created a function to check who all have salary less then 25000. If the above case renders rows then I call the procedure from my function.

The procedure updates the `sal` (`sal = sal + 1000`) and returns rowcount.

```
create procedure Taxrefund2(@taxr int) as
begin
    update customer 
    set Balance=Balance + @taxr

    return @@rowcount
end

create function taxfunc()
as
begin
   declare @salary table(sal decimal(10,2))

   set @salary = (select sal from customer)

   declare @x int=0

   if @salary < 25000
      exec @x = taxrefund2(1000)

   return @x

   print 'the no of customers who got tax redeemption is :' +cast(@x as varchar(10))
```

When I compile my function I am getting errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure taxfunc, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure taxfunc, Line 8
>   Incorrect syntax near '1000'.
>
> Msg 178, Level 15, State 1, Procedure taxfunc, Line 9
>   A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure taxfunc, Line 10
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Can someone explain me what wrong have I done either in the code or the concept?

Comment: You cannot call a stored procedure inside a sql server User-defined function. And you cannot change the state of database inside a function, but what ever you are trying to do in your code can be achieved in ONE STORED PROCEDURE :)

Comment: Why do you have tags of both SQL Server and MySql?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to call a stored procedure in a user defined function ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843788/is-it-possible-to-call-a-stored-procedure-in-a-user-defined-function)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a stored procedure directly from User defined Function.

[How to call a stored procedure from a user defined function In SQL Server 2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070871/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-from-a-user-defined-function-in-sql-2000)

Comment: Actually this isn't entirety true, there is an exception.. see the post I linked as a duplicate..

Comment: Not the downvoter, but why repeating the same answer? and you have one more comment that states a problem with your answer.. and he isn't using SQL Server 2000...

Comment: Yosi, i seen. You be there. I am sharing the repeated question. I felt you are not able to find the answer from stackoverflow. Most questions are already asked